# Executing Workflows Error Coudify

Tags: cloudify

I am following tutorial http://getcloudify.org/guide/3.2/getting-started-execute-workflow.html to execute workflows, but when running the command:

```
cfy executions start -w install -d nodecellar
```

Is the error below:

```
...
2015-10-17T18:15:59 CFY <nodecellar> [nodejs_host_ae3cc.start] Task started 'ec2.instance.start'
2015-10-17T18:16:00 CFY <nodecellar> [mongod_host_0d2c0.start] Task rescheduled 'ec2.instance.start' -> OperationRetry('Waiting server to be running. Retrying...',) [attempt 1]
2015-10-17T18:16:00 CFY <nodecellar> [nodejs_host_ae3cc.start] Task rescheduled 'ec2.instance.start' -> OperationRetry('Waiting server to be running. Retrying...',) [attempt 1]
2015-10-17T18:16:00 CFY <nodecellar> 'install' workflow execution failed: RuntimeError: Workflow failed: Task failed 'ec2.instance.start' -> OperationRetry('Waiting server to be running. Retrying...',)
Execution of workflow 'install' for deployment 'nodecellar' failed. [error=Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/cloudify.nodecellar_workflows/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/decorators.py", line 264, in child_wrapper
    ctx, func, args, kwargs)
  File "/root/cloudify.nodecellar_workflows/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/decorators.py", line 370, in _execute_workflow_function
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/cloudify.nodecellar_workflows/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/plugins/workflows.py", line 552, in install
    InstallationTasksGraphFinisher
  File "/root/cloudify.nodecellar_workflows/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/plugins/workflows.py", line 174, in _install_node_instances
    graph.execute()
  File "/root/cloudify.nodecellar_workflows/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/workflows/tasks_graph.py", line 125, in execute
    self._handle_terminated_task(task)
  File "/root/cloudify.nodecellar_workflows/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/workflows/tasks_graph.py", line 191, in _handle_terminated_task
    task.error))
RuntimeError: Workflow failed: Task failed 'ec2.instance.start' -> OperationRetry('Waiting server to be running. Retrying...',)
]
* Run 'cfy events list --include-logs --execution-id 2c7ea17c-1a4c-4081-a1fb-6fdd066a539d' to retrieve the execution's events/logs
```

When running:

```
cfy events list --include-logs --execution-id 2c7ea17c-1a4c-4081-a1fb-6fdd066a539d
```

I received:

```
Getting events from management server 107.21.102.232 for execution id '2c7ea17c-1a4c-4081-a1fb-6fdd066a539d' [include_logs=True]
2015-10-17T18:15:47 CFY <nodecellar> Starting 'install' workflow execution
2015-10-17T18:15:47 CFY <nodecellar> [mongod_security_group_59cc8] Creating node
2015-10-17T18:15:48 CFY <nodecellar> [nodecellar_security_group_cb839] Creating node
2015-10-17T18:15:48 CFY <nodecellar> [nodecellar_elasticip_b3e1d] Creating node
2015-10-17T18:15:48 CFY <nodecellar> [mongod_security_group_59cc8.create] Sending task 'ec2.securitygroup.create'
2015-10-17T18:15:48 CFY <nodecellar> [nodecellar_security_group_cb839.create] Sending task 'ec2.securitygroup.create'
2015-10-17T18:15:48 CFY <nodecellar> [nodecellar_elasticip_b3e1d.create] Sending task 'ec2.elasticip.allocate'
2015-10-17T18:15:48 CFY <nodecellar> [mongod_security_group_59cc8.create] Task started 'ec2.securitygroup.create'
2015-10-17T18:15:48 CFY <nodecellar> [nodecellar_security_group_cb839.create] Task started 'ec2.securitygroup.create'
2015-10-17T18:15:48 CFY <nodecellar> [nodecellar_elasticip_b3e1d.create] Task started 'ec2.elasticip.allocate'
2015-10-17T18:15:52 CFY <nodecellar> [nodecellar_security_group_cb839.create] Task succeeded 'ec2.securitygroup.create'
2015-10-17T18:15:52 CFY <nodecellar> [nodecellar_elasticip_b3e1d.create] Task succeeded 'ec2.elasticip.allocate'
2015-10-17T18:15:52 CFY <nodecellar> [nodecellar_security_group_cb839] Configuring node
2015-10-17T18:15:52 CFY <nodecellar> [mongod_security_group_59cc8.create] Task succeeded 'ec2.securitygroup.create'
2015-10-17T18:15:52 CFY <nodecellar> [nodecellar_elasticip_b3e1d] Configuring node
2015-10-17T18:15:52 CFY <nodecellar> [mongod_security_group_59cc8] Configuring node
2015-10-17T18:15:53 CFY <nodecellar> [nodecellar_security_group_cb839] Starting node
2015-10-17T18:15:53 CFY <nodecellar> [nodecellar_elasticip_b3e1d] Starting node
2015-10-17T18:15:54 CFY <nodecellar> [mongod_security_group_59cc8] Starting node
2015-10-17T18:15:54 CFY <nodecellar> [nodejs_host_ae3cc] Creating node
2015-10-17T18:15:54 CFY <nodecellar> [nodejs_host_ae3cc.create] Sending task 'ec2.instance.run_instances'
2015-10-17T18:15:54 CFY <nodecellar> [nodejs_host_ae3cc.create] Task started 'ec2.instance.run_instances'
2015-10-17T18:15:54 CFY <nodecellar> [mongod_host_0d2c0] Creating node
2015-10-17T18:15:54 CFY <nodecellar> [mongod_host_0d2c0.create] Sending task 'ec2.instance.run_instances'
2015-10-17T18:15:54 CFY <nodecellar> [mongod_host_0d2c0.create] Task started 'ec2.instance.run_instances'
2015-10-17T18:15:58 CFY <nodecellar> [nodejs_host_ae3cc.create] Task succeeded 'ec2.instance.run_instances'
2015-10-17T18:15:58 CFY <nodecellar> [mongod_host_0d2c0.create] Task succeeded 'ec2.instance.run_instances'
2015-10-17T18:15:58 CFY <nodecellar> [mongod_host_0d2c0] Configuring node
2015-10-17T18:15:59 CFY <nodecellar> [nodejs_host_ae3cc] Configuring node
2015-10-17T18:15:59 CFY <nodecellar> [mongod_host_0d2c0] Starting node
2015-10-17T18:15:59 CFY <nodecellar> [nodejs_host_ae3cc] Starting node
2015-10-17T18:15:59 CFY <nodecellar> [mongod_host_0d2c0.start] Sending task 'ec2.instance.start'
2015-10-17T18:15:59 CFY <nodecellar> [mongod_host_0d2c0.start] Task started 'ec2.instance.start'
2015-10-17T18:15:59 CFY <nodecellar> [nodejs_host_ae3cc.start] Sending task 'ec2.instance.start'
2015-10-17T18:15:59 CFY <nodecellar> [nodejs_host_ae3cc.start] Task started 'ec2.instance.start'
2015-10-17T18:16:00 CFY <nodecellar> [mongod_host_0d2c0.start] Task rescheduled 'ec2.instance.start' -> OperationRetry('Waiting server to be running. Retrying...',) [attempt 1]
2015-10-17T18:16:00 CFY <nodecellar> [nodejs_host_ae3cc.start] Task rescheduled 'ec2.instance.start' -> OperationRetry('Waiting server to be running. Retrying...',) [attempt 1]
2015-10-17T18:16:00 CFY <nodecellar> 'install' workflow execution failed: RuntimeError: Workflow failed: Task failed 'ec2.instance.start' -> OperationRetry('Waiting server to be running. Retrying...',)

Total events: 38
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you provide the following: 1) Output of `cfy version`; 2) Location in GitHub from where you obtained the Nodecellar application & blueprints

Comment: Output: Cloudify CLI 3.2.1 Cloudify Manager 3.2.1 (build: 85, date: ). I am using as an example, brach 3.2.1: https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-nodecellar-example/tree/3.2.1-build